# Are the airports of Abu Dhabi (AUH) and Dubai (DWC/DXB) considered to be serving the same region?

Tags: airports, legal, cancellations, refunds

This question relates to the definition of *flight cancellation*, following the following statement on the European Union's official information page for air passenger rights:

> Cancellation occurs when:
>
> - your original flight schedule is abandoned and you are transferred to
>   another scheduled flight
> - the aircraft took off but, was forced to
>   return to the airport of departure and you were transferred to
>   another flight
> - **your flight arrives at an airport which is not the final destination indicated on your ticket, unless:**
>
>   - You accepted re-routing (under comparable transport conditions at
>     the earliest opportunity) to the airport of your original final
>     destination or to any other destination agreed by you. In this case it is considered as a delay and not a cancellation.
>   - **The airport of
>     arrival and the airport of the original final destination serve the
>     same town, city or region. In this case it is considered as a delay
>     and not a cancellation.**

Furthermore, it is stated that:

> If your flight is cancelled you have the right to choose between reimbursement, re-routing or return.

(Source: https://www.google.com/amp/s/europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/indexamp_en.htm)

I am wondering whether AUH and DWC are generally considered to be serving the same region, and if a passenger whose flight destination was changed from DWC to AUH has the right to reimbursement.

My guess would be that AUH and DWC are serving seperate regions, as the United Arab Emirates are an agglomerate of different regions, each having their own laws which generally go further in differences among each other, than differences in laws between provinces in other countries (for example, between Bundesländern in Germany). AUH and DWC are in different emirates.

Comment: It is a 95km driving distance between AUH and DWC, and 131 km between AUH and DXB.

Comment: Did an airline cancel a flight you were planning to take and offer you AUH/DWC as an alternative, or is your interest here only theoretical?

Comment: Hi mlc, an airline (Wizz Air) indeed changed my destination airport (as DWC was temporarily closed due to COVID-19) and informed me well in advance. However, I was not offered reimbursement. So, yes, it is related to a personal situation, but I'm genuinely interested in how this situation is legally perceived as well.

Comment: My guess is that it will have to be ruled on by a court, since the actual rule seems to be too vague. But it is possible for airports at that distance to be in the same "region". For example, in the USA, BOS (Boston Logan airport) is 87km driving distance from MHT (Manchester-Boston Regional Airport), an airport to which flights to BOS sometimes divert. Commuter buses run several times a day between the two airports and the center of Boston. People who live here will routinely fly to or from either airport. It is easy to argue that these airports are in the same region.

Comment: I am not sure about AUH and DWC though this may give you some ideas on how you might make an argument.